# How to fix "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" problem?

Tags: kotlin

I make database with SQLite in Kotlin, and then when i deleted the first data and then i deleted the last data the problem show up.

I've been trying to make id: Int = 0, but still not work

fun deleteCaption(caption: Caption){

```
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    // Delete Caption by ID
    db.delete(
        TABLE_CAPTION,"$COLUMN_CAPTION_ID = ?",
        arrayOf(caption.id.toString())
    )
    db.close()
}
```

I expect when i deleted the first data and then i deleted the last data it's work but the actual that's no work

Comment: this my project on github : https://github.com/abdhilabs/yourcaption

Answer (score 0):

IndexOutOfBound means that you are trying to use an element that is too 'far' in the array.
For example, if you have an array of size 3, the possible index are : 0, 1, 2.
So you can't get array[3].

Are you sure your array is not empty ?
Are you removing entries of your array inside a `forEach` loop on your array ?

Comment: Sure, my array is not empty, i think the problem is in primary key, isn't?

Comment: @AbdhiLabs Certainly, are you sure you are using the right primary key ? What do you have in your array ?

Comment: In my array just primary key and one data, but primary key is auto generate

Comment: Why would you auto generate a primary key ? How do you access to your data if you do not even know which key to use to get it ?